# Trying to get property 'category_name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to access the parent category data. I can access the object which works perfectly. But when I'm trying to show the data on the table this error shows :

"Trying to get property 'category_name' of non-object (View: F:\project\resources\views\admin\sub_categories.blade.php)"

```
public function allSubCategory(){
        $categoryArr = SubCategory::with('Category')->get();
        return view('admin.sub_categories', compact('categoryArr'));
    }
```

here is the function I defined inside the controller. when I try to access the object as "`<td>{{$subcategories->category}}</td>`" the object can be seen in the table in a JSON format. But when I try to access the data as "`<td>{{$subcategories->category->category_name}}</td>`" this error occurs.

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "cat_ID": 3,
    "sub_category_name": "Pagol",
    "created_at": "2021-03-22T12:43:10.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-03-22T12:43:10.000000Z",
    "category": {
      "id": 3,
      "category_name": "Manush",
      "created_at": "2021-03-17T13:51:10.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-03-17T13:51:10.000000Z"
    }
```

How am I supposed to access the "category_name" from here and show only this onto the table?

Thank you for taking the time. I really appreciate it.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOaK3.jpg)

Comment: don't just put pictures of your code..it makes people to downvote your question..code is text..update your question with proper format and add your relationship code too in the question..

Comment: Try to check with `dd($subcategories->category)` the `category_name`  is `object` or `array`

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually new here. Thank you for the suggestion. I will do that from next time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `$subcategories->category->category_name` is unsafe code when executed in a Loop. If any of your `$subcategories` doesn't have a `category`, then it will fail, as `null->category_name` is invalid. You need to check, like `$subcategories->category ? $subcategories->category->category_name : 'No Category'`, or `$subcategories->category?->category_name` if using PHP 8. Also, you need to post your code, including how you're defining `$categoryArr`, and `$subcategories` as a bad variable name; should be `$subcategory` (singular), since it represents a single row.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will follow them from now on. Is the format of the question is easier for you to understand now?

Comment: Yes, it's much better :) Always remember that code is text, and copy/pasting/formatting it directly into your question is better than pasting as an image. Images are welcome as a supporting document to visually explain something, but code is almost always required. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion and also your patience. But I couldn't find a solution for the problem yet. :'(

Comment: how are you defining the relationship?? is it `Category` or `category`??

Comment: I have updated the question. when I put ""$subcategories->category" . The JSON format of the category can be seen onto the table. But when I'm trying to access the "category_name". This error occurs. Sorry If my question seems complicated. I'm a new developer learning on my own.

Comment: it seems at least one of your sub category is missing `cat_ID`..make sure you have that in all rows of the sub category table..try using the code tim showed..you can identify which row is causing the issue that way.